# VBS to press tab then enter when uninstalling program

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I am trying to create a VBS to press 'tab' or 'left arrow' then hit 'enter'.

I have tried this from two approaches:

1-attempt. I have to where it opens the uninstall program, runs it. It focuses on the window but nothing happens, no commands 'tab' 'left' or 'enter' are passed.

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Run("""Path to uninstall\unins000.exe""")
ObjShell.AppActivate("uninstall")
WScript.sleep 4000
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("{LEFT}")
```

2-attempt.Double click uninstall option (can have this done another way) then the uninstall window appears. I am able to set the focus on this window but the command 'tab' or 'left' nothing happens. I even just tried 'enter' to see if will do anything and nada.

```
Dim ObjShell :Set ObjShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
ObjShell.AppActivate("uninstall")
Wscript.sleep 1000
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("{TAB}")
```

Even went old school created vbs to open notepad, enter words then move to next line and save it self. Which worked, so something I am missing not doing correctly.

If someone is able to help, I have been googling and looking at video and so far nothing is clicking.

Comment: SendKeys scripts are rarely reliable and VBScript provides too few options to fine tune GUI interaction. You may have more control and better reliability using [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me. Moved .Sleep before AppActivate because if I clicked elsewhere and the uninstall dialog box lost focus, then only this way it would come back into focus.

The code is using Alt + Y key combination to confirm uninstall, and not Left + Enter keys.

Careful, the code below should uninstall your program directly. Replace the y in the last 2 lines with n to test how it cancels uninstall.

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Run("""Path to uninstall\unins000.exe""")
WScript.Sleep 4000
ObjShell.AppActivate("uninstall")
ObjShell.SendKeys "%y"
ObjShell.SendKeys "y"
```